# How do I indicate foil blocking to a printer?

Tags: print-design, print-production

One of our clients had a set of stationery made by us, and it looks really great, even though printing design is not our thing (not at all, we do interaction design).

Anyways, when looking for printing options, I have found *foil blocking*, which  fits exactly in what I wanted for the design. Now, it's not possible for me to go to the printer since they're not even in my own country, thus I think I need to inform the printer which part should use *foil blocking*. Is enough to let them know *"this logo uses foil blocking"* or is there any specific convention to do this?

Comment: Assuming your artwork has been set up properly, the logo should be a solid spot colour, then you just set the name of the colour to "foil block".  And obviously tell your printer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1: 2 PDF**

If you send the PDF to the printer, send a second PDF the same size as the original with just the foil blocking area filled with a Pantone ink color or just 100% black.

**Option 2: 1 PDF with a *special layer***

At the same document, make a separate layer with the foil blocking area filled with a Pantone ink color and indicate that this is the *special printing area*

Printing PDF:

[image]

Foil blocking PDF:

[image]

Comment: It's foil blocking.